# Get value as list in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe has one colum of type list, it looks something like this:

```
Genre                                              Band
['deep pop r&b', 'indie r&b', 'r&b', 'trap soul'], Elijah Blake
```

I'm iterating the dataframe using iterrows(), but when I get the column value it is a string, how can I can load as a list?

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    artist_genres = row['Genres']  #this is a string
    print(artist_genres)   
    for artist_genre in artist_genres:
        print(artist_genre)        #this prints each character, I want to iterate each genre
```

Comment: expected output?

Comment: what about `df["Genres"].tolist()`

Comment: `artist_genres` should be a list, how did you get it as a string?

Comment: @pygo tolist() returns a list of each character `['[', '\'', 'd', ...]`

Comment: @bakka `row['Genres']` returns a string, even if I saved a list in that dataframe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast
df['Genre'] = df['Genre'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use eval to convert a string that is actually a list to list

```
artist_genres = eval(row['Genres'])
```